# Computers that can represent only N states

Tags: computer-science, binary

In computation, with every new bit added, the number of possible states multiplies by a factor of 2. So the number of states in a computer is 2^N, where N is the number of bits we have. Is there a model of computation that only has N states. For example, if you add another piece of data, you only add one to the total number of states. Do specialized algorithms exist for something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use a base-1 computer, it will, theoretically, be able to represent only $N$ states.

Comment: Yes, consider a memory that is just a pile of indistinguishable tokens, e.g. rocks. If the maximum size of the pile is $N-1$ then the only information in a state is how many tokens there are so there are $N$ possible states. But why would you want this?